# Video positioning issue HTML mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a full screen video that takes the entirety of the page.  The video shows up with it's full width and height on desktop. However, it only shows a section of it on mobile. That's fine, although I want to change that section of the video that shows to move to the left. 
This is a visual aid to show what I am trying to ask: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU9qc.jpg

This is my code:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="header7.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>



<style>
    #myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}




}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your video fullscreen on any screen I would suggest changing the `min-width` and `max-width` properties to `width` and `height` and using viewport units.
An approach could be:

```css
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Note that I changed your video `src` to a placeholder one for explanation sake.

**EDIT:** Looks like Stack Overflow doesn't allow the video, here's a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y854cds2/)**

**EDIT 2:** If you just want to move the video to the left on mobile, just play with the `right` property until it is positioned where you want it. Make sure to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: Ok, so on mobile, there is no way to blow it up and change the section that is shown? Because I think it looks more optimized if the video fills the entire screen.

Comment: Check the second edit. Keep using `max-width` and `max-height` and play with the `right` property values. You'll notice how the section shown changes.